# Shutdown @Bean ExecutorService using @PreDestroy

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, executorservice, predestroy

I have a Spring @Configuration class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class ExecutorServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue() {
        return ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
    }     

    @Bean
    public ExecutorService executor(BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue) {
        return ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdownExecutor() {
        // no executor instance
    }
}
```

I would also like to specify a `@PreDestroy` method which shuts down the ExecutorService. However, the `@PreDestroy` method cannot have any arguments which is why I'm not able to pass the `executor` bean to this method in order to shut it. Specifying destroy method in `@Bean(destroyMethod = "...")` does not work either. It allows me to specify existing `shutdown` or `shutdownNow`, but not the custom method which I intend to use.

I know I could instantiate the queue and executor directly and not as Spring beans, but I'd rather do it this way.

Comment: Instead of returning the ThreadPoolExecutor directly, add it to a container then return it and use the container in your shutdownExecutor method?

Comment: you could separate creation and management of the executor and autowire it to the service, or you could assign it to a private member in this class thereby making it visible to `shutdownExecutor()`. You could also ask `ApplicationContext.getBean()` but getting beans out of context is considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: I thought about assigning it to the private variable, but I found it somehow ugly. Shutting it down in other component is an option.

Comment: @zenn1337 I don't find a private variable ugly at all provided the executor service is actually a singleton.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love defining classes inline:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "myCustomShutdown")
public ExecutorService executor(BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue) {
        public void myCustomShutdown() {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which does all that by default.

```
@Configuration
public class ExecutorServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
            protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
                return new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(queueCapacity);
            }
        };
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        taskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(0);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(1000);
        return taskExecutor;
    }    
}
```

This will configure the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and shutdown when the application stops.

If you don't need the `ArrayBlockingQueue` but can live with the default `LinkedBlockingQueue` and only need to specify the queue capacity you can remove the override `createQueue` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's probably the best I could do. I'm however accepting gpeche's answer  since it directly resolves the `@PreDestroy` issue. I do need to have the queue as a separate bean, cause I have to be able to clear all queued unprocessed tasks if some event occurs.